# Mongo restore command reduces database size

Tags: database, mongodb

I have two clusters of mongo database, each having three machines. Say Cluster1 and Cluster2. To reduce cost I have to terminate Cluster2. So I took mongodump of one database from the primary machine of Cluster2 which is 8.5 GB. I copied that dump folder to the primary machine of Cluster1 and run there mongorestore command but when I run `show dbs` command on Cluster1 it shows the size as 4.7GB. So my question is, did I make any mistake or mongorestore does not restore indexes or any other reason?

Comment: does anybody have answer for it? It is quite urgent for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that your storage size (which `show dbs` indicates) varies on restore, especially if the original deployment had a lot of space available for reuse (for example, due to document deletion). A `mongodump` backs up data and index definitions, and the `mongorestore` process will rebuild the data files and indexes for restored collections.

For a better comparison of your original and restored deployments you should review the `db.stats()` output.

Assuming there weren't any issues with the backup & restore process, both deployments should have a similar number of databases, collections, indexes, and objects. If your original deployment was being actively written to while (or after) the `mongodump` was taken, the outcome may differ slightly.

For example, to output stats for all databases via the `mongo` shell:

```
db.adminCommand('listDatabases').databases.forEach(function(d) {
    printjson(db.getSiblingDB(d.name).stats());
})
```

Comment: Thanks Stennie... perfect solution.